# Improve edit for tag description

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

I just noticed that while questions/answers reviews have "Improve Edit" button, there is no such thing for tags excerpts. I faced pending edit with typos, but couldn't do anything about it, just "Accept" or "Reject".

So, it'd be nice to have ability to improve tag edits too. And what should i do in such situations? Just move on?

Comment: meta se duplicate [Ability to edit a suggested edit to a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267317)

Comment: Isn't there? Not sure just now, but it would certainly require the privilige of making unreviewed edits (20K).